# Search for and format text within parentheses

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have text in a Word document that contains parentheses. I would like to format a word within these parentheses.

Example text:

> The presence of a black hole can be inferred through its interaction
> with other matter and with electromagnetic radiation such as visible
> light. Any matter (that falls onto a black hole can) form an external
> accretion disk heated by friction, forming quasars, some of the
> brightest objects in the universe.

Formatted text:

> The presence of a black hole can be inferred through its interaction
> with other matter and with electromagnetic radiation such as visible
> light. Any matter (that falls onto a ***black*** hole can) form an external
> accretion disk heated by friction, forming quasars, some of the
> brightest objects in the universe.

In the formatted text, the word 'black' is in bold and italics if it appears within parentheses.

I found a way to identify all the words within the parentheses. How do I apply formatting?

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .Text = "(\(*\))"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Absolutely no need to use RegEx. You can do this with Find and Replace, so why didn’t you just record a macro to give you the correct syntax?

Comment: That does not work. Please check it once.

Comment: It *does work*. See the answer from Taller which does exactly what your question asks for.

Comment: Sorry. My understanding was poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word search and replace is powerful enough to get it done w/o RegExp.

```vb
Sub BlackInParentheses()
    Dim rng As Range, new_rng As Range
    Dim text As String, sSrhTxt As String
    Const KEYWORD = "black" ' Modify as needed
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    ' search KEYWORD, sSrhTxt = "\(*<[Bb]lack>*\)"
    sSrhTxt = "\(*<[" & UCase(Left(KEYWORD, 1)) & _
        LCase(Left(KEYWORD, 1)) & "]" & Mid(KEYWORD, 2) & ">*\)"
    Debug.Print sSrhTxt
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .text = sSrhTxt
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Forward = True
    End With
    Do While rng.Find.Execute
'        Debug.Print rng.text
        Set new_rng = rng.Duplicate
        ' sSrhTxt = "(<[bB]lack>)"
        sSrhTxt = "(<[" & UCase(Left(KEYWORD, 1)) & _
            LCase(Left(KEYWORD, 1)) & "]" & Mid(KEYWORD, 2) & ">)"
        With new_rng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .text = sSrhTxt
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Forward = True
            ' Change font
            With .Replacement
                .ClearFormatting
                .text = "\1"
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Italic = True
            End With
            ' replace w/ format
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This works for only one instance. What if I have multiple instances?

Comment: The updated code is more reliable to replace all instances.  Please share your document content in OP if it doen't work well w/ your document.

Comment: The one thing I would change is to make KEYWORD an input argument rather than a constant.

Answer (score 2):

I would put VBA in Word, and modify the code as follows:

```
Sub ReplacInParentheses (beforeWord as string, afterWord as string)
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Global = True
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Pattern = "\(([^)]*)\)"
    
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    For Each match In regex.Execute(doc.Range.Text)
        Dim newText As String
        newText = Replace(match.SubMatches(0), beforeWord, afterWord)
        doc.Range.Text = Replace(doc.Range.Text, match.Value, "(" & newText & ")")
    Next match
End Sub

Sub test()
 ReplacInParentheses "black", "white"
End Sub
```

Comment: OP is interested in altering the font attributes (bold and italics) of keywords.